# Sonar web client- Updating a value fails

Tags: java, rest, sonarqube

I am trying to modify an existing manual metric in sonar from externally 
supplied value using the web service client.
So far I am able to read the existing metric value from the plugin, but 
am having doubts in updating the values.

Also, on updating the metric like

```
sonar.update(new PropertyUpdateQuery("<metric_key>, "Metric Value"));
```

Nothing happens, but the [javadocs](http://docs.sonarsource.org/2.7/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html) mention about the PUT operation in the UpdateQuery class.
Edit: I have also tried to update the method using this approach :

```
        UpdateQuery<Metric> update = new UpdateQuery<Metric>() {
        @Override
        public Class<Metric> getModelClass() {
            return Metric.class;
        }
        @Override
        public String getUrl() {
            return "/drilldown/measures/70?metric=<Metric Key>";
        }
    };
    sonar.update(update);
```

Is this the correct method of updating a manual metric ?
Also, should the model class and url be something more specific ? - No documentation for this exists so far.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with the REST API, the best is to visit the following page: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API

There, you can find the [available operations on manual measures](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API#WebServiceAPI-ManualMeasures): get, create and delete. There's no update operation on manual measures.

BTW, the equivalent in the Java Web Service Client are ManualMeasure*Query, not PropertyUpdateQuery which updates Sonar properties.